# Pass all data from 2 column MySQL table into Python variable

Tags: python, mysql, twitter, machine-learning, text-classification

I'm trying to pass all data from 2 column (label, tweets) from my table in MySQL into Python variable and use it as training data for my classifier. what I want is for example if I print(data[0]), then I can get ([('tweet'), 'label'] using the code below

```html
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import *



#Connect to database and get the data
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost:3306/machinelearning')
tweet = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT label, tweets FROM tweetstable', engine)
etweet = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT tweet, label FROM evaluatetweets', engine)

reviews = [(list(tweet.tweets(fileid)), label)
           for label in tweet.label()
           for fileid in tweet.fileids(label)]

train = reviews[0:100]

print(train[0])
```

but when I run it, it gives me error.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Indra/PycharmProjects/TextClassifier/textblobclassifier.py", line 13, in <module>
    for label in tweet.label()
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Label is not a function, so the `()` after tweet.label should be removed.

Comment: I removed the () but I still get the same error

Comment: @ayhan can you somehow help me please? :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the structure of your tables, and I don't really understand what you are trying to calculate in your `review`. Anyway, I hope this might help: the result of `read_sql_query` is a dataframe, thus you have to treat it as such.

In the example below the table "tweet" contains a dump of tweets, I select just 2 columns to make the query somewhat similar to yours, and I select the column "id" for first five rows in the most straightforward way.

```
In [9]:
tweets = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT id, tweet FROM tweet', engine)

In [10]:
print(tweets[0:5]["id"])
0    595577027517915136
1    595577004763848706
2    595576984845049856
3    595576968365613057
4    595576966394314754
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

You can also access directly to the column, which is I guess what you would like to do, just with `tweets['id']` and anyway use the indexing for pandas dataframes, see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: well I actually finally found the way to solve my problem.. but thanks for answering my question. :)

Comment: No problem. It would be nice if you answered your own question, since it could be useful for somebody else having a similar problem. Cheers.